# jdbc to my sql connectivity

Tags: java, jdbc

This is my java code for jdbc connectivity:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class dbtest
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
    {
        String host = "127.0.0.1.mysql.com";
        String dbName = "emp";
        int port = 3306;
        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/emp";


        try
        {
            Class.forName("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/emp");           
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.out.println("Error loading driver: ");
        }


        String password = "pavilion";
        Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,password);
        DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData =connection.getMetaData();
        String productName =dbMetaData.getDatabaseProductName();
        System.out.println("Database: " + productName);

        productVersion =dbMetaData.getDatabaseProductVersion();
        System.out.println("Version: " + productVersion);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String query ="SELECT * FROM emp";
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + " " +resultSet.getString(2));
        }
        connection.close();
    } 
}
```

Errors:

```
Error loading driver:  
 Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found 
  forjdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/emp
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:640)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
at dbtest.main(dbtest.java:40)
```

Answer (score 4):

instead of this

```
Class.forName("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/emp");
```

do this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: this is giving                                                                   Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable             driver found for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: You'll need the mysql driver .jar file in the classpath of your program.

Comment: CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar
    export CLASSPATH

     CLASSPATH=".:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar"

Comment: Process: 1 learn what a classpath is.  2. put the mysql driver in your class path.  Try a google search on "what is a java classpath"

Comment: CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar
export CLASSPATH

CLASSPATH=".:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar"    where should i  save this and with which extension

Comment: (1.) download the jar http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html (2.) copy it on the classpath of your program. If you have difficulties with (2.) then refer to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java) or ask how to do it in an other thread. good luck!

Comment: Don't set a CLASSPATH environment variable.  Very bad idea.